# Creating a column in a Python/Pandas dataframe that shows examples of what data is in that respective Column from an Excel Source

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Goal: Create a column that either: 1. Displays the three most common entries, or 2: Displays three random discrete entries of the column in the source excel file. I know that's a lot of words, let me demonstrate. In the example below, I am having trouble writing the code to produce what's in the **right-most column** of the **second table below** (The Sample Values column).

Given this source excel file (NBA.xlsx):

| Final_Game_Day | Champion | MVP | String_Example | Average_Viewership_(millions) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/11/2020 | Lakers | LeBron James | LeBron wins 4th championship; Lakers win record tying 17th | 7.45 |
| 6/13/2019 | Raptors | Kawhi Leonard | Toronto wins 1st championship denying Warriors 3-peat | 15.14 |
| 6/8/2018 | Warriors | Kevin Durant | Warriors sweep Cavs for back-to-back championships | 17.56 |
| 6/12/2017 | Warriors | Kevin Durant | Durant wins first after leaving OKC | 20.38 |
| 6/19/2016 | Cavaliers | LeBron James | Cavs win their 1st ever title | 20.28 |
| 6/16/2015 | Warriors | Andre Iguodala | Iguodala first 6th man to win MVP | 19.94 |

I want:

| ---------- | Column_Name | File_Names | Data_Type | Sample_Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| File1.Final_Game_Day | Final_Game_Day | NBA.xlsx | datetime64[ns] | 10/11/2020; 6/13/2019; 6/8/2018 |
| File1.Champion | Champion | NBA.xlsx | object | Warriors; Lakers; Raptors |
| File1.MVP | MVP | NBA.xlsx | object | LeBron James; Kevin Durant; Kawhi Leonard |
| File1.String_Example | String_Example | NBA.xlsx | object | LeBron wins 4th championship; Lakers win record tying 17th; Toronto wins 1st championship denying Warriors 3-peat; Warriors sweep Cavs for back-to-back championships |
| File1.Average_Viewership_(millions) | Average_Viewership_(millions) | NBA.xlsx | float64 | 7.45; 15.14; 17.56 |

I will provide the code below. It's long, but I want to give you an idea of what I'm working with. I think I only need to add some snippets of code in the last two sections denoted by the # sign:

```
### Setting up
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

###Setting working directory
path = os.getcws()
files = os.listdir(path)

### Prep to get all files
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

### Reading only excel files in folder
FileList_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == "xlsx"]

# Initializing empty data frame
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Initializing Aggregate List for Column Names
Agg_ColumnNames = []

# Initializing Aggregate List for File Names associated with Column Names
FileNames = []

# Initializing empty dataframe for Data Type
datatype_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Read excel into Python and prepping the dataframe for DATA TYPE ONLY
n = 1
for f in FileList_xlsx:
    test_df = pd.read_excel(f)
    test_df = test_df.add_prefix(f'File{n}.')
    datatype_df = datatype_df.append(test_df, ignore_index=True, sort = False)
    n+=1

# Getting the data type of the column

dataTypeSeries = datatype_df.dtypes

# Loop over list of Excel files

for f in FileList_xlsx:
    ReadXlsx = pd.read_excel(f)
    ColumnNames = list(ReadXlsx.columns.values)

    for a in ColumnNames:
        Agg_ColumnNames.append(a)
    
    for a in ColumnNames:
        FileNames.append(f)

# Create final dataframe
final = {'Column_Name': Agg_ColumnNames, 'File_Name': FileNames, 'Data_Type': dataTypeSeries}
```

Comment: why is the dataTypeSeries array content is "NBA.xlsx" ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Something screwed up with the formatting. Fixing it now.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Should be fixed now.